# Is there a way to set up automatic deletion of checkpointed DataFrame in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am running Spark in local mode and use checkpoint as I have some severe memory constraints. I run this code quite often and manually need to clear my checkpoint directory every so often (the checkpointed DataFrames are quite large). Is there a way to set it up so that when the SparkSession closes it automatically clears the checkpoint directory?

Comment: No, this isn't supported by Spark.